# Is there an example of how to use akka-http with servlet container?

Tags: scala, servlets, akka, spray, akka-http

Right now using [spray](http://spray.io/) with [Servlet30ConnectorServlet](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-servlet/src/main/scala/spray/servlet/Servlet30ConnectorServlet.scala) successfully in tomcat and was hoping to find similar example usage with [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/http/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any connector servlet in akka-http yet.

You can have a look at the api here: [Akka http API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/0.4/#package)