# Akka (Java) configure custom ThreadFactory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, akka

For one of my projects I want to use Akka client in a Java EE 7 environment. 
Threads should be managed by the container in Java EE. Therefore I want to override the default Akka's `ThreadFactory` or `ExecutorService`.
I can't find the answer in their documentation, anyone idea about this?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/scala/http.html)

Comment: @AxelH that link is for an ancient version of Akka.  Nothing in there is relevant.

Comment: @Ryan, my bad, I didn't checked the version I was reading ... There is a ["recent" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629111/is-there-an-example-of-how-to-use-akka-http-with-servlet-container) looking to use it with Tomcat but this will not help much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if this is required you have to take a different approach: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/java/futures.html